# OTR Microwave vent through wall, but on bottom?

Tags: ducts, ventilation, microwave-oven, range-hood

I was replacing my over-the-range microwave and discovered the location of the existing vent. The vent is straight out the exterior wall, but down towards the bottom mounting bracket… I can’t seem to find any OTR microwave options that accommodate a vent location like this. Seems like they all have the vent fan near the top of the microwave. What are my options? Is there a fancy vent duct adapter that I could use? Or am I going to have to open up the wall and relocate the vent?

Thank you in advance for any help/tips!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did the removed microwave have a bottom-vent? You don't necessarily have to do anything. The space behind/above the oven can be considered a plenum, air fan-forced into it will exit at any available outlet.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move the duct opening. I've never encountered a bottom-exit microwave.

Fortunately, this doesn't look too challenging in your case. I'd cut the drywall to correspond with the unit's exit, then cut the sheet metal. You may be able to simply partition the duct at the bottom of the new opening, or you can just block the original opening.

Use foil tape and sheet metal panels as needed to get it all sealed up, and consider a foam tape on the wall to prevent leakage there.